# Adding text field dynamically when clicked on button in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a text field with button pickerView functionality.

```
if(pickerView==selectItemListPickerView)
{
    selectITemListTxtFld.text = [itemListSplitDisplayArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Now I want to display this functionality in another dynamically created text field each time when I click on add button. I tried it like this.

```
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 350, 309, 35)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.tag = 44;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
```

Like this I am getting only one text field dynamically. So please do the needful.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new text fields but adding them on top of each other.

Consider keeping an index as global variable in the class/controller

```
{
NSInteger textFieldCount = 0;
}
```

After you create a text field increment it

```
textFieldCount += 1;
```

And use this index in this line

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 350 + textFieldCount*35, 309, 35)];
```

You will add text fields one step down each time you create new one.

Comment: i am getting error here textFieldCount*35 , UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 350 + textFieldCount * 35, 309, 35)]..